# MongoDB crashes during sort when using indexes

Tags: mongodb

I have a problem with my mongodb that crashes for certain queries during sort operation. I cannot pinpoint the exact conditions when the crashes occur but they occur mainly when I have compound index created (the same queries executed without any added indexes do not cause crash). I don't think I hit the memory limit for sorting (I don't get any error message) and I don't know what can be the root cause of the problem.

I use collection 'products' of about 40k documents. The document generic structure is:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5fa263aa97ec9d1372130ba4"),
  "brand" : "product_brand",
  "line" : "product_line",
  "gender" : "female",
  "type" : "product_type",
  "size" : 50,
  "tester" : false,
  "isSet" : false,
  "imagePath" : "product_image_path",
  "offers" : [
               {
                 "shopName" : "shop1_name",
                 "shopNameReal" : "shop1_name_real",
                 "title" : "product_title",
                 "price" : 100,
                 "url" : "product_shop_url"
                },
                {
                 "shopName" : "shop2_name",
                 "shopNameReal" : "shop2_name_real",
                 "title" : "product_title",
                 "price" : 100,
                 "url" : "product_shop_url"
                },
                {
                 "shopName" : "shop3_name",
                 "shopNameReal" : "shop3_name_real",
                 "title" : "product_title",
                 "price" : 100,
                 "url" : "product_shop_url"
                },
  ]
}
```

(offers array can contain up to 200 objects)

I use indexes:

```
{brand: 1},
{gender: 1},
{brand: 1, line: 1, gender: 1, type: 1, size: 1, isSet: 1, tester: 1, "offers.0.price": 1}
```

Example shell query causing crash:

```
db.products.find({brand: 'product_brand'}).sort({gender: 1})
```

Mongodb version 4.4.1, running on VPS with Ubuntu server 18.04.

Logs from /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log after executing the above query

```
{
  "t": {
    "$date": "2020-11-04T10:11:25.465+00:00"
  },
  "s": "F",
  "c": "-",
  "id": 23079,
  "ctx": "conn1",
  "msg": "Invariant failure",
  "attr": {
    "expr": "elt.type() != BSONType::Array",
    "file": "src/mongo/db/index/btree_key_generator.cpp",
    "line": 75
  }
}
{
  "t": {
    "$date": "2020-11-04T10:11:25.465+00:00"
  },
  "s": "F",
  "c": "-",
  "id": 23080,
  "ctx": "conn1",
  "msg": "\n\n***aborting after invariant() failure\n\n"
}
{
  "t": {
    "$date": "2020-11-04T10:11:25.466+00:00"
  },
  "s": "F",
  "c": "CONTROL",
  "id": 4757800,
  "ctx": "conn1",
  "msg": "Writing fatal message",
  "attr": {
    "message": "Got signal: 6 (Aborted).\n"
  }
}
{
  "t": {
    "$date": "2020-11-04T10:11:25.654+00:00"
  },
  "s": "I",
  "c": "CONTROL",
  "id": 31431,
  "ctx": "conn1",
  "msg": "BACKTRACE: {bt}",
  "attr": {
    "bt": {
      "backtrace": [
        {
          "a": "55F4393909F1",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "2CC89F1",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail12_GLOBAL__N_119printStackTraceImplERKNS1_7OptionsEPNS_14StackTraceSinkE.constprop.606",                                                                                         
          "s+": "1E1"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F439392029",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "2CCA029",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceEv",
          "s+": "29"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F43938F886",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "2CC7886",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_116abruptQuitActionEiP9siginfo_tPv",
          "s+": "66"
        },
        {
          "a": "7FA8B5965980",
          "b": "7FA8B5953000",
          "o": "12980",
          "s": "funlockfile",
          "s+": "50"
        },
        {
          "a": "7FA8B55A0FB7",
          "b": "7FA8B5562000",
          "o": "3EFB7",
          "s": "gsignal",
          "s+": "C7"
        },
        {
          "a": "7FA8B55A2921",
          "b": "7FA8B5562000",
          "o": "40921",
          "s": "abort",
          "s+": "141"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F4375D04C9",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "F084C9",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo15invariantFailedEPKcS1_j",
          "s+": "12C"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F4374899CF",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "DC19CF",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_128extractNonArrayElementAtPathERKNS_7BSONObjENS_10StringDataE.cold.323",
          "s+": "2E"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F4383CD61E",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "1D0561E",
          "s": "_ZNK5mongo17BtreeKeyGenerator20_getKeysWithoutArrayERKNS_7BSONObjEN5boost8optionalINS_8RecordIdEEEPSt3setINS_9KeyString5ValueESt4lessISA_ESaISA_EE",                                                          
          "s+": "1CE"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F4383CF2DE",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "1D072DE",
          "s": "_ZNK5mongo17BtreeKeyGenerator7getKeysERKNS_7BSONObjEbPSt3setINS_9KeyString5ValueESt4lessIS6_ESaIS6_EEPSt6vectorIS4_ImS7_ImESaImEESaISF_EEN5boost8optionalINS_8RecordIdEEE",                                   
          "s+": "8E"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F43807C59E",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "19B459E",
          "s": "_ZNK5mongo17BtreeAccessMethod9doGetKeysERKNS_7BSONObjENS_17IndexAccessMethod14GetKeysContextEPSt3setINS_9KeyString5ValueESt4lessIS8_ESaIS8_EESD_PSt6vectorIS6_ImS9_ImESaImEESaISH_EEN5boost8optionalINS_8RecordIdEEE",                                                                                                       
          "s+": "4E"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F43814AB6A",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "1A82B6A",
          "s": "_ZNK5mongo25AbstractIndexAccessMethod7getKeysERKNS_7BSONObjENS_17IndexAccessMethod11GetKeysModeENS4_14GetKeysContextEPSt3setINS_9KeyString5ValueESt4lessIS9_ESaIS9_EESE_PSt6vectorIS7_ImSA_ImESaImEESaISI_EEN5boost8optionalINS_8RecordIdEEESt8functionIFvNS_6StatusES3_SP_EE",                                              
          "s+": "8A"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F4380EB235",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "1A23235",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo16WorkingSetCommon5fetchEPNS_16OperationContextEPNS_10WorkingSetEmNS_11unowned_ptrINS_20SeekableRecordCursorEEERKNS_15NamespaceStringE",                                                             
          "s+": "6F5"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F4380B58E6",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "19ED8E6",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo10FetchStage6doWorkEPm",
          "s+": "136"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F4380CBA58",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "1A03A58",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo9PlanStage4workEPm",
          "s+": "68"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F4380C5175",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "19FD175",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo14MultiPlanStage12workAllPlansEmPNS_15PlanYieldPolicyE",
          "s+": "135"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F4380C53DF",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "19FD3DF",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo14MultiPlanStage12pickBestPlanEPNS_15PlanYieldPolicyE",
          "s+": "9F"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F43810EF92",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "1A46F92",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo16PlanExecutorImpl13_pickBestPlanEv",
          "s+": "92"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F438111860",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "1A49860",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo16PlanExecutorImpl4makeEPNS_16OperationContextESt10unique_ptrINS_10WorkingSetESt14default_deleteIS4_EES3_INS_9PlanStageES5_IS8_EES3_INS_13QuerySolutionES5_ISB_EES3_INS_14CanonicalQueryES5_ISE_EERKN5boost13intrusive_ptrINS_17ExpressionContextEEEPKNS_10CollectionENS_15NamespaceStringENS_12PlanExecutor11YieldPolicyE",                                                                                                       
          "s+": "200"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F438111A2C",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "1A49A2C",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo12PlanExecutor4makeESt10unique_ptrINS_14CanonicalQueryESt14default_deleteIS2_EES1_INS_10WorkingSetES3_IS6_EES1_INS_9PlanStageES3_IS9_EEPKNS_10CollectionENS0_11YieldPolicyENS_15NamespaceStringES1_INS_13QuerySolutionES3_ISH_EE",                                                                                  
          "s+": "10C"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F438105BB9",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "1A3DBB9",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo11getExecutorEPNS_16OperationContextEPNS_10CollectionESt10unique_ptrINS_14CanonicalQueryESt14default_deleteIS5_EENS_12PlanExecutor11YieldPolicyEm",                                                  
          "s+": "149"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F438105D0F",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "1A3DD0F",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_116_getExecutorFindEPNS_16OperationContextEPNS_10CollectionESt10unique_ptrINS_14CanonicalQueryESt14default_deleteIS6_EENS_12PlanExecutor11YieldPolicyEm",                               
          "s+": "6F"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F438105DA1",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "1A3DDA1",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo15getExecutorFindEPNS_16OperationContextEPNS_10CollectionESt10unique_ptrINS_14CanonicalQueryESt14default_deleteIS5_EEbm",                                                                            
          "s+": "51"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F437D6B525",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "16A3525",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_17FindCmd10Invocation3runEPNS_16OperationContextEPNS_3rpc21ReplyBuilderInterfaceE",                                                                                                     
          "s+": "A25"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F4382F6FBF",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "1C2EFBF",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo14CommandHelpers20runCommandInvocationEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_12OpMsgRequestEPNS_17CommandInvocationEPNS_3rpc21ReplyBuilderInterfaceE",                                                         
          "s+": "7F"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F437AB06B5",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "13E86B5",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_114runCommandImplEPNS_16OperationContextEPNS_17CommandInvocationERKNS_12OpMsgRequestEPNS_3rpc21ReplyBuilderInterfaceENS_11LogicalTimeERKNS_23ServiceEntryPointCommon5HooksEPNS_14BSONObjBuilderERKNS_30OperationSessionInfoFromClientE",                                                               
          "s+": "135"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F437AB3519",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "13EB519",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_119execCommandDatabaseEPNS_16OperationContextEPNS_7CommandERKNS_12OpMsgRequestEPNS_3rpc21ReplyBuilderInterfaceERKNS_23ServiceEntryPointCommon5HooksE",                                  
          "s+": "11B9"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F437AB47DB",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "13EC7DB",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_116receivedCommandsEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_7MessageERKNS_23ServiceEntryPointCommon5HooksE",                                                                                        
          "s+": "62B"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F437AB541D",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "13ED41D",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo23ServiceEntryPointCommon13handleRequestEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_7MessageERKNS0_5HooksE",                                                                                                        
          "s+": "50D"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F437AA332C",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "13DB32C",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo23ServiceEntryPointMongod13handleRequestEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_7MessageE",
          "s+": "3C"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F437AAD9AC",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "13E59AC",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine15_processMessageENS0_11ThreadGuardE",
          "s+": "FC"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F437AAB6E5",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "13E36E5",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine15_runNextInGuardENS0_11ThreadGuardE",
          "s+": "125"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F437AAC696",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "13E4696",
          "s": "_ZNSt17_Function_handlerIFvvEZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine22_scheduleNextWithGuardENS2_11ThreadGuardENS1_9transport15ServiceExecutor13ScheduleFlagsENS4_23ServiceExecutorTaskNameENS2_9OwnershipEEUlvE_E9_M_invokeERKSt9_Any_data",                                                                                          
          "s+": "56"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F438D571E2",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "268F1E2",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo9transport26ServiceExecutorSynchronous8scheduleESt8functionIFvvEENS0_15ServiceExecutor13ScheduleFlagsENS0_23ServiceExecutorTaskNameE",                                                               
          "s+": "182"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F437AAAAFB",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "13E2AFB",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine22_scheduleNextWithGuardENS0_11ThreadGuardENS_9transport15ServiceExecutor13ScheduleFlagsENS2_23ServiceExecutorTaskNameENS0_9OwnershipE",                                        
          "s+": "DB"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F437AABE5D",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "13E3E5D",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine15_sourceCallbackENS_6StatusE",
          "s+": "6AD"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F437AABF40",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "13E3F40",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo14future_details4callIRZNS_19ServiceStateMachine14_sourceMessageENS2_11ThreadGuardEEUlNS_10StatusWithINS_7MessageEEEE0_S6_EEDaOT_OT0_",                                                              
          "s+": "60"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F437AAC1C5",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "13E41C5",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine14_sourceMessageENS0_11ThreadGuardE",
          "s+": "145"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F437AAB75A",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "13E375A",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine15_runNextInGuardENS0_11ThreadGuardE",
          "s+": "19A"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F437AAC696",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "13E4696",
          "s": "_ZNSt17_Function_handlerIFvvEZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine22_scheduleNextWithGuardENS2_11ThreadGuardENS1_9transport15ServiceExecutor13ScheduleFlagsENS4_23ServiceExecutorTaskNameENS2_9OwnershipEEUlvE_E9_M_invokeERKSt9_Any_data",                                                                                          
          "s+": "56"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F438D57848",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "268F848",
          "s": "_ZNSt17_Function_handlerIFvvEZN5mongo9transport26ServiceExecutorSynchronous8scheduleESt8functionIS0_ENS2_15ServiceExecutor13ScheduleFlagsENS2_23ServiceExecutorTaskNameEEUlvE0_E9_M_invokeERKSt9_Any_data",   
          "s+": "B8"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F4390AAEA6",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "29E2EA6",
          "s": "_ZNSt17_Function_handlerIFvvEZN5mongo25launchServiceWorkerThreadESt8functionIS0_EEUlvE1_E9_M_invokeERKSt9_Any_data",                                                                                          
          "s+": "56"
        },
        {
          "a": "55F4390AAF14",
          "b": "55F4366C8000",
          "o": "29E2F14",
          "s": "_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_17runFuncEPv",
          "s+": "14"
        },
        {
          "a": "7FA8B595A6DB",
          "b": "7FA8B5953000",
          "o": "76DB",
          "s": "start_thread",
          "s+": "DB"
        },
        {
          "a": "7FA8B568371F",
          "b": "7FA8B5562000",
          "o": "12171F",
          "s": "clone",
          "s+": "3F"
        }
      ],
      "processInfo": {
        "mongodbVersion": "4.4.1",
        "gitVersion": "ad91a93a5a31e175f5cbf8c69561e788bbc55ce1",
        "compiledModules": [],
        "uname": {
          "sysname": "Linux",
          "release": "4.15.0-122-generic",
          "version": "#124-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 13:03:05 UTC 2020",
          "machine": "x86_64"
        },
        "somap": [
          {
            "b": "55F4366C8000",
            "elfType": 3,
            "buildId": "832AC9AE6CC5692FB33A92460CF800BB1B8C176A"
          },
          {
            "b": "7FA8B5953000",
            "path": "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0",
            "elfType": 3,
            "buildId": "AE13B309B7DE1CC2B1CBC7605FC174DAC01A90FC"
          },
          {
            "b": "7FA8B5562000",
            "path": "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6",
            "elfType": 3,
            "buildId": "CC6DD208D3AF4BC505F599A90EF8AF52F16116E4"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does your system log say that it's killed mongo due to lack of memory by any chance…?

Comment: The syslog only says:

`Nov  4 15:40:25 vps-c3f3677d systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
Nov  4 15:40:25 vps-c3f3677d systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'signal'.`


Clearly mongodb asks the Operating system to stop it so it is probably not the situation when OS decides by itself to kill a process using to much memory.

Comment: `code=killed` very much sounds like the OS killing it; I doubt mongod would commit suicide.

Comment: Well. From I've read trying to solve the problem signal 6 in mongodb logs means that mongodb
found itself in situation tha it cannot function correctly and sends signal to OS to be killed. But I'm not sure if this is the case.